# xmlserializer strips xlink from xlink:html svg image tag

Tags: javascript, html, svg, xmlserializer

I'm creating a javascript interface to dynamically add xlinked images to a map of a classroom.

```
 //declare the xlink namespace in the svg header
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
...
//the code to append the image
var temp = document.createElementNS(svgns,"image");
temp.setAttributeNS(null,"x","0");
temp.setAttributeNS(null,"y","0");
temp.setAttributeNS(null,"height","80");
temp.setAttributeNS(null,"width","40");
temp.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink","xlink:href","roomlayouts/items/ cactus.svg");
```

The image appends and displays on the screen with tags like so:

```
<image x="0" y="0" height="80" width="40" xlink:href="roomlayouts/items/cactus.svg"></image>
```

But once I pass it through the xmlserializer so that I can save the file, it strips the xlink tag off the front:

```
var svgDoc = document.getElementById('SVGMap');
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var xmlString = serializer.serializeToString(svgDoc.firstChild);
```

creating:

```
<image x="0" y="0" width="40" height="80" href="roomlayouts/items/cactus.svg"></image>
```

This means the svg loses the cactii.  Any ideas how I can get the xmlserializer to keep the xlink prefix?

==============================
NOTE: this was a bug in webkit that has now been resolved.  See discussion below for link to bug report

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Further Investigation

I have created a [test SVG file on my server](http://phrogz.net/SVG/image.svg) that:

1. Has an `<image>` with properly-namespaced `href` attribute in it.
2. Uses JS to create a new `<image>` using `setAttributeNS(xlinkNS,'xlink:href',…)`
3. Uses JS to create a new `<image>` using `setAttributeNS(xlinkNS,'href',…)`
4. Uses JS to clone the original (valid) `<image>` element.
5. Finally, serializes the XML and logs the result.

#### Results in WebKit

The Safari and Chrome Developer Tools both show the DOM as:

```
<image xlink:href="…" />
<image xlink:href="…" />
<image href="…" />
<image xlink:href="…" />
```

However, the XML serialization logged to the console (which is what you also get if you right click the Element and say "Copy as HTML") shows this:

```
<image xlink:href="…" />
<image xlink:href="…" />
<image href="…" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
<image xlink:href="…" />
```

#### Results in Firefox

Firebug also shows this for the generated DOM:

```
<image xlink:href="…" />
<image xlink:href="…" />
<image href="…" />
<image xlink:href="…" />
```

However, the Firebug Console shows a reasonable (expected) serialization:

```
<image xlink:href="…" />
<image xlink:href="…" />
<image xlink:href="…" />
<image xlink:href="…" />
```

Further investigation shows that even if you use code like:

```
img.setAttributeNS(xlinkNS,'GLARBLE:href',…);
```

Firebug will show "GLARBLE:href" as the name of the attribute, but the XML serialization uses the URI for the namespace, finds the matching namespace on the root `<svg>` element and properly produces:

```
<image xlink:href="…" />
```

### Conclusion

It appears that the XML serialization performed by Webkit is flawed (broken) when using `setAttributeNS` to create a namespaced attribute with no namespace prefix provided for the attribute name.

However, if you provide a namespace prefix for the attribute name that matches a namespace prefix already declared on your document, the serialization appears to work correctly.

Comment: Hi Phrogz, You're making me think that my issue might lie elsewhere.  Once I make the svg, I serialise it and save it.  When I try and reload it everything loads but the plants.  If I edit the file and add the xlink: before the html tag then they appear, hence my attempt to use xlink:html instead of plain html.  Any idea why they aren't appearing?

Comment: @pluke See my update and investigation. Are you creating your `<svg>` element programmatically, and if so how/where are you setting a general XLink namespace prefix?

Comment: I'm using: <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" ....> with some other name space declarations. Does that sound ok? I need to look more closely at your code and see if there are any differences.  As far as I can see when I dynamically create the image it displays in the same way as your [2.] but when I serialise it to save it the xlink is stripped and when I reload it it won''t display at all.

Comment: If you use `var xlinkNS = svg.getAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:xlink');` instead it works in Opera but not the others, if OTOH you do `var xlinkNS = svg.getAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xlink');` then it works in all of them. NOTE: With "works" I only mean that the image shows up four times, not that it's serialized the same way. Also see http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Namespaces-Considerations.

Comment: I think I've found part of the issue, when I programmatically make the svg, I build the svg header tag as a string with the code: `<svg xmlns="w3.org/2000/svg"; xmlns:xlink="w3.org/1999/xlink"; ....>`  but once this is serialised it strips off the xmlns: leaving: `<svg xmlns="w3.org/2000/svg"; xlink="w3.org/1999/xlink"; ....>` meaning it doesn't handle the xlink correctly. Any ideas on how to stop the serialiser doing all this tag stripping?

Comment: @pluke Why don't you build the `<svg>` node programmatically and set the `xmlns:xlink` attribute directly on there?

Comment: @Phrogz, I'll give it a shot and let you know if that fixes anything.

Comment: @Phrogz. I've constructed it programmatically: `var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
 var newEl = document.createElementNS(xmlns,"svg");
 newEl.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns', xmlns);
 newEl.setAttributeNS(xmlns,"xlink","http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
 newEl.setAttributeNS(xmlns,"dc","http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"); ...` 
But it's not making much of a difference, and won't let me `setAttributeNS(xmlns,"xmlns:xlink","http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");` complaining of a NAMESPACE_ERR DOM Ex 14

Comment: `ewEl.setAttributeNS(xmlns,"xlink","http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");` should be `ewEl.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/',"xmlns:xlink","http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");`

Comment: @Phrogz still having no luck, the chrome serializer butchers the xmlns tag out of the svg.  Firebox does a better job, serializing the svg code so it displays in chrome, but bizarrely not in firefox.  I haven't tested in IE.  Take a look at the example here: http://kemputing.com/demo/importImage.html

Comment: FYI this is now registered as a bug and in the process of getting fixed: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=79586